# My KNN model - Vector to data.frame issue

Tags: r, knn

I need your help this time. I'm working on my KNN model (looking for their probabilities).

```
predictions<- knn(x_training, x_testing, y_training, k = 5, prob = TRUE)
```

However, I'd like to get a dataframe with it. When I applied the data.frame function, I get only 0/1 (whether is true or false) but not the probability.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult to understand your question, you should try to give us a reproducible example with code. It is much easier for us as a community to answer your questions efficiently if you do.

Here is an example:

```
library(class)
train <- rbind(iris3[1:25,,1], iris3[1:25,,2], iris3[1:25,,3])
test <- rbind(iris3[26:50,,1], iris3[26:50,,2], iris3[26:50,,3])
cl <- factor(c(rep("s",25), rep("c",25), rep("v",25)))
predictions <- knn(train, test, cl, k = 3, prob=TRUE)
```

I believe you are running into trouble because you are trying to coerce the output of the KNN function into a dataframe. However, the KNN output has the probabilities as an attribute of the data.

So you need to access the probabilities using the attr() function. For more info type:

```
?attr
```

into the R console.

To achieve your desired outcome you need to do this:

```
data.frame(Value=predictions,Prob=attr(predictions,"prob"))
```